# Save as GeoPackage Layer Options - use of Description and Identifier

Tags: qgis, metadata, geopackage

When saving a layer as GeoPackage in QGIS 3, what is the purpose of the Layer Options DESCRIPTION and IDENTIFIER?

[image]

I'm looking at how we can manage our working data better than the current mess of shape files.  When you hover over DESCRIPTION the tooltip says "Human-readable description for the layer content".  I thought this might useful to as quick way to provide some documentation/metadata as to the purpose of each layer.
However the DESCRIPTION and IDENTIFIER don't seem to be exposed anywhere that I can find. When looking at the geopackage in the Browser or DB Manager or the add layer dialog I see only the table name, no DESCRIPTION or IDENTIFIER.  Am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This information gets added to the Metadata statement of the layer.

in QGIS, if you right click - properties - Metadata, you will see where the information is and available to edit.
I believe Identifier gets added to the Title field, whilst the Description gets added to the Abstract.

This is also available for view on the Information summary page of the layer. Check it out in scree grab below.

[image]

Comment: Sweet! So it does.  Both QGIS 3.4 and 3.10 are installed on the machine I was using - 3.4 was opening by default when I double clicked a .qgs file.  Once I started using 3.10 the metadata appeared. Thank you.